# Enforcing AppArmor Profile on Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, apparmor

This is **not** about (Docker) container AppArmor profiles but this is about enforcing the Docker **Daemon** AppArmor profile.

[Docker's AppArmor-related documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/) only briefly mentions that the profile for the engine daemon doesn't get installed with Debian packages and then [links to .go files](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/master/contrib/apparmor) in the code repository.

How do I get this working, that is, how do I apply the profile to my Docker engine for some testing?

Any attempt at go install `github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/apparmor/main.go@latest` or go install `github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/apparmor/main.go@master` fails with `module github.com/moby/moby@latest found (v20.10.6+incompatible), but does not contain package github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/apparmor` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why there's such a lack of documentation on their part, but I think you could just cut and paste most of that `.go` file into a valid AppArmor profile. The only thing you would need to edit is the sections such as `{{if ge .Version 209000}}`, where you would remove the `{{if ... }}` `{{end}}` markers if your docker daemon is new enough (>= 20.09), or remove those sections entirely if for some reason you're running an older daemon.

So I was able to save this as `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.docker`:

```
@{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}=/var/lib/docker

profile /usr/bin/docker flags=(attach_disconnected, complain) {
  # Prevent following links to these files during container setup.
  deny /etc/** mkl,
  deny /dev/** kl,
  deny /sys/** mkl,
  deny /proc/** mkl,

  mount -> @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/**,
  mount -> /,
  mount -> /proc/**,
  mount -> /sys/**,
  mount -> /run/docker/netns/**,
  mount -> /.pivot_root[0-9]*/,

  / r,

  umount,
  pivot_root,
  signal (receive) peer=@{profile_name},
  signal (receive) peer=unconfined,
  signal (send),
  network,
  capability,
  owner /** rw,
  @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/** rwl,
  @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/network/files/boltdb.db k,
  @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/network/files/local-kv.db k,
  # For user namespaces:
  @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/[0-9]*.[0-9]*/network/files/boltdb.db k,
  @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/[0-9]*.[0-9]*/network/files/local-kv.db k,

  # For non-root client use:
  /dev/urandom r,
  /dev/null rw,
  /dev/pts/[0-9]* rw,
  /run/docker.sock rw,
  /proc/** r,
  /proc/[0-9]*/attr/exec w,
  /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/ r,
  /etc/localtime r,
  /etc/ld.so.cache r,
  /etc/passwd r,

  ptrace peer=@{profile_name},
  ptrace (read) peer=docker-default,
  deny ptrace (trace) peer=docker-default,
  deny ptrace peer=/usr/bin/docker///bin/ps,

  /usr/lib/** rm,
  /lib/** rm,

  /usr/bin/docker pix,
  /sbin/xtables-multi rCx,
  /sbin/iptables rCx,
  /sbin/modprobe rCx,
  /sbin/auplink rCx,
  /sbin/mke2fs rCx,
  /sbin/tune2fs rCx,
  /sbin/blkid rCx,
  /bin/kmod rCx,
  /usr/bin/xz rCx,
  /bin/ps rCx,
  /bin/tar rCx,
  /bin/cat rCx,
  /sbin/zfs rCx,
  /sbin/apparmor_parser rCx,

  # Transitions
  change_profile -> docker-*,
  change_profile -> unconfined,

  profile /bin/cat (complain) {
    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /lib/** rm,
    /dev/null rw,
    /proc r,
    /bin/cat mr,

    # For reading in 'docker stats':
    /proc/[0-9]*/net/dev r,
  }
  profile /bin/ps (complain) {
    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /etc/localtime r,
    /etc/passwd r,
    /etc/nsswitch.conf r,
    /lib/** rm,
    /proc/[0-9]*/** r,
    /dev/null rw,
    /bin/ps mr,

    # We don't need ptrace so we'll deny and ignore the error.
    deny ptrace (read, trace),

    # Quiet dac_override denials
    deny capability dac_override,
    deny capability dac_read_search,
    deny capability sys_ptrace,

    /dev/tty r,
    /proc/stat r,
    /proc/cpuinfo r,
    /proc/meminfo r,
    /proc/uptime r,
    /sys/devices/system/cpu/online r,
    /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max r,
    /proc/ r,
    /proc/tty/drivers r,
  }
  profile /sbin/iptables (complain) {
    signal (receive) peer=/usr/bin/docker,
    capability net_admin,
  }
  profile /sbin/auplink flags=(attach_disconnected, complain) {
    signal (receive) peer=/usr/bin/docker,
    capability sys_admin,
    capability dac_override,

    @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/aufs/** rw,
    @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/tmp/** rw,
    # For user namespaces:
    @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/[0-9]*.[0-9]*/** rw,

    /sys/fs/aufs/** r,
    /lib/** rm,
    /apparmor/.null r,
    /dev/null rw,
    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /sbin/auplink rm,
    /proc/fs/aufs/** rw,
    /proc/[0-9]*/mounts rw,
  }
  profile /sbin/modprobe /bin/kmod (complain) {
    signal (receive) peer=/usr/bin/docker,
    capability sys_module,
    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /lib/** rm,
    /dev/null rw,
    /apparmor/.null rw,
    /sbin/modprobe rm,
    /bin/kmod rm,
    /proc/cmdline r,
    /sys/module/** r,
    /etc/modprobe.d{/,/**} r,
  }
  # xz works via pipes, so we do not need access to the filesystem.
  profile /usr/bin/xz (complain) {
    signal (receive) peer=/usr/bin/docker,
    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /lib/** rm,
    /usr/bin/xz rm,
    deny /proc/** rw,
    deny /sys/** rw,
  }
  profile /sbin/xtables-multi (attach_disconnected, complain) {
    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /lib/** rm,
    /sbin/xtables-multi rm,
    /apparmor/.null w,
    /dev/null rw,

    /proc r,

    capability net_raw,
    capability net_admin,
    network raw,
  }
  profile /sbin/zfs (attach_disconnected, complain) {
    file,
    capability,
  }
  profile /sbin/mke2fs (complain) {
    /sbin/mke2fs rm,

    /lib/** rm,

    /apparmor/.null w,

    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /etc/mke2fs.conf r,
    /etc/mtab r,

    /dev/dm-* rw,
    /dev/urandom r,
    /dev/null rw,

    /proc/swaps r,
    /proc/[0-9]*/mounts r,
  }
  profile /sbin/tune2fs (complain) {
    /sbin/tune2fs rm,

    /lib/** rm,

    /apparmor/.null w,

    /etc/blkid.conf r,
    /etc/mtab r,
    /etc/ld.so.cache r,

    /dev/null rw,
    /dev/.blkid.tab r,
    /dev/dm-* rw,

    /proc/swaps r,
    /proc/[0-9]*/mounts r,
  }
  profile /sbin/blkid (complain) {
    /sbin/blkid rm,

    /lib/** rm,
    /apparmor/.null w,

    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /etc/blkid.conf r,

    /dev/null rw,
    /dev/.blkid.tab rl,
    /dev/.blkid.tab* rwl,
    /dev/dm-* r,

    /sys/devices/virtual/block/** r,

    capability mknod,

    mount -> @{DOCKER_GRAPH_PATH}/**,
  }
  profile /sbin/apparmor_parser (complain) {
    /sbin/apparmor_parser rm,

    /lib/** rm,

    /etc/ld.so.cache r,
    /etc/apparmor/** r,
    /etc/apparmor.d/** r,
    /etc/apparmor.d/cache/** w,

    /dev/null rw,

    /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/** r,
    /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/.replace w,

    /proc/[0-9]*/mounts r,
    /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease r,
    /proc r,

    capability mac_admin,
  }
}
```

Then I loaded the profile into complain mode for testing: `aa-complain /usr/bin/docker`.

You can see that it's loaded with `aa-status`:

```
13 profiles are in complain mode.
   /usr/bin/docker
   /usr/bin/docker///bin/cat
   /usr/bin/docker///bin/ps
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/apparmor_parser
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/auplink
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/blkid
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/iptables
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/mke2fs
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/modprobe
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/tune2fs
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/xtables-multi
   /usr/bin/docker///sbin/zfs
   /usr/bin/docker///usr/bin/xz
```

Then, you can restart your docker daemon/containers, watch for profile violations in your syslog, and adjust the profile in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.docker` if something breaks.

When you're statisfied with the profile, then you just put it into enforce mode:

```
aa-enforce /usr/bin/docker
```

One other thing to consider is that this only covers `/usr/bin/docker`, but not `/usr/bin/dockerd` or `/usr/bin/containerd`, so I think to get full AppArmor coverage for docker itself one would also need to write profiles for those.

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor